# How to alter Core's user login final function

Tags: 7, hooks, users

In user.module, I need to alter the message that is displayed if the username/password is not recognized. I'm using the email registration module so I don't use usernames at all. I want the last form error message in the code below to show email/password instead, as well as add a custom redirect to it.

I've googled for quite some time, but cannot find how to hook onto this function. Any help would be appreciated!

```
function user_login_final_validate($form, &$form_state) { 
  if (empty($form_state['uid'])) {
  // Always register an IP-based failed login event.
  flood_register_event('failed_login_attempt_ip', variable_get('user_failed_login_ip_window', 3600));
  // Register a per-user failed login event.
  if (isset($form_state['flood_control_user_identifier'])) {
  flood_register_event('failed_login_attempt_user', variable_get('user_failed_login_user_window', 21600), $form_state['flood_control_user_identifier']);
}

if (isset($form_state['flood_control_triggered'])) {
  if ($form_state['flood_control_triggered'] == 'user') {
    form_set_error('name', format_plural(variable_get('user_failed_login_user_limit', 5), 'Sorry, there has been more than one failed login attempt for this account. It is temporarily blocked. Try again later or <a href="@url">request a new password</a>.', 'Sorry, there have been more than @count failed login attempts for this account. It is temporarily blocked. Try again later or <a href="@url">request a new password</a>.', array('@url' => url('user/password'))));
  }
  else {
    // We did not find a uid, so the limit is IP-based.
    form_set_error('name', t('Sorry, too many failed login attempts from your IP address. This IP address is temporarily blocked. Try again later or <a href="@url">request a new password</a>.', array('@url' => url('user/password'))));
  }
}
else {
  // Fix password reset messages
  form_set_error('name', t('Sorry, unrecognized username or password. <a href="@password">Have you forgotten your password?</a>', array('@password' => url('user/password', array('query' => array('name' => $form_state['values']['name']))))));
  watchdog('user', 'Login attempt failed for %user.', array('%user' => $form_state['values']['name']));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the validation function then you need to add it to the `#validate` part of the form array in `hook_form_alter`:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'MY_user_login_final_validate';
  }
}
```

You will need to examine the `$form['#validate']` array to remove the current user module validation and possibly adjust the weight of the module in the `system` table.

To redirect you add something like the following to hook_form_alter:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_redirect_node_form_submit';
```

Again bearing in mind you might need to alter/re-order the current contents of `$form['#submit']` and the system table weight.

OR if you want to simply change the string then you could do it in a number of ways.

1. The string overrides module: https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides
2. Put the overrides in the settings.php file:

   ```
   $conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
     'Sorry, unrecognized username or password. <a href="@password">Have you forgotten your password?</a>' => 'YOUR MESSAGE HERE',
   );
   ```
3. Put this in `hook_boot()` :

   ```
   global $conf;
   $conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
     'Sorry, unrecognized username or password. <a href="@password">Have you forgotten your password?</a>' => 'YOUR MESSAGE HERE',
   );
   ```

The trick is to replicate exactly what is in the string surrounded by `t('') in the user module (currently this is line 2228).

```
      form_set_error('name', t('Sorry, unrecognized username or password. <a href="@password">Have you forgotten your password?</a>', array('@password' => url('user/password', array('query' => array('name' => $form_state['values']['name']))))));
```

Then you can let the Drupal string translation system take care of it for you.  See here for a reference on [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2116803)

Comment: Great thanks for detailed resposne, I will try it today.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I was able to hook into that validation process but the user.module validation still is called last. I changed the user.module weight to 9018 (my module weight is 9001) in the system table, cleared caches several times but user.module's validation is still winning... I also tried pushing my hook's weight to the top as described in [http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/hook-module-implements-alter-not-working-for-me-what-am-i-doing-wrong](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/hook-module-implements-alter-not-working-for-me-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Comment: I can't check today but I thought that the heavier weighted modules were called later, so is just that you need to make your module weight greater than the user module's?

Comment: You were right. I changed the user.module weight to 7018, and now it's working well! I was having another issue that was confusing since both the user.module and my module were throwing a form_set_error on the same element, therefore I would only see the user.module error. I had to use drupal_get_messages('error'); to clear the user's error, and then only my module's error was showing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Override login form with [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

You need to replace validation function with your custom function.